# Subquery Issues with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with summing two different columns based of the item id with a subquery. I want to get the sum of Profit and Qtyship from 7/1/16 onward to attach to each Invtid per ShipDate. I appreciate the help thanks in advance!

Current:

```
ShipDate   InvtID      Qtyship   Profit
7/19/2016  Item101         4     $20
7/21/2016  Item101         5     $25
7/1/2016   Product411     11     $44
7/1/2016   Product411     14     $56
```

Here is what it should look like:

```
ShipDate   InvtID      Qtyship   Profit   Total Qtyship   Total Profit
7/19/2016  Item101         4     $20          9                $45
7/21/2016  Item101         5     $25          9                $45
7/1/2016   Product411     11     $44          25               $100
7/1/2016   Product411     14     $56          25               $100
```

The query code:

```
select h.shipdate, h.invcnbr,
l.invtid, l.slsprice, l.qtyship, l.totcost,
l.slsprice*l.qtyship as revenue,
(l.slsprice*l.qtyship)-l.TotCost as Profit
from opsshipper h
join opshipline l on h.shipperid=l.shipperid where h.invcdate>='7/1/2016' 
and l.qtyship<>0 and l.slsprice>0 order by h.invcdate,l.invtid
```

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT  h.shipdate, 
        h.invcnbr,
        l.invtid, 
        l.slsprice, 
        l.qtyship, 
        l.totcost,
        l.slsprice*l.qtyship as revenue,
        (l.slsprice*l.qtyship)-l.TotCost as Profit,
        SUM(l.qtyship) OVER(PARTITION BY l.invtid) [Total Qtyship],
        SUM((l.slsprice*l.qtyship)-l.TotCost) OVER(PARTITION BY l.invtid) [Total Profit]
FROM opsshipper h
INNER JOIN opshipline l 
    ON h.shipperid = l.shipperid 
WHERE h.invcdate >= '20160701' 
AND l.qtyship <> 0 
AND l.slsprice > 0 
ORDER BY h.invcdate,l.invtid;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I never knew about the over clause its a game changer.

Answer (score 0):

following simple solution should work:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT InvtID,SUM(Qtyship) TotalQtyShip,SUM(Profit) TotalProfit
    FROM OpsShipper 
    WHERE ShipDate>='2016-07-01'
)
SELECT a.ShipDate,a.InvtID,a.QtyShip,a.Profit,c.TotalQtyShip,c.TotalProfit
FROM OpsShipper a JOIN CTE c ON c.InvtID=a.InvtID
WHERE ShipDate>='2016-07-01';
```

Comment: you can add more condition to polish the result but this SQL should return the result that you said you want.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to get the output from your provided table details. 
You can use simple query like below to get the sum of Profit and Qtyship from 7/1/16 onward.

Queries I used to generate the required output:

```
create table shipment(
ShipDate datetime,
InvtID varchar(50),
QtyShip int,
Profit money
)

insert into shipment
values
('7/19/2016','Item101',4,'$20'),
('7/21/2016','Item101',5,'$25'),
('7/1/2016','Product411',11,'$44'),
('7/1/2016','Product411',14,'$56')

select 
    replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ShipDate, 101),'-','/') as ShipDate,   
    InvtID,
    QtyShip,
    Profit,
    SUM(qtyship) over(partition by invtid) as TotalQtyShip,
    SUM(profit) over (partition by invtid) as TotalProfit
from shipment
where ShipDate > '07/01/2016'
```

Output:
[image]